# css nth-child first n selector isn't working with hover state

Tags: css

I have 9 divs inside a flex container.

[image: divs]

What I'm trying to achieve is an effect where the div you're hovering over 'pushes' the divs on the right further right and the divs on the left further left. I'd like to do this using nth-child selector so that I only have to write 2 styles for each div.

For now, I just have it partialy working on the red div as a proof of concept.

Achieving the first part was easy, when you hover over the red div, the 4 divs to the right of it are pushed to the right using `translateX(30px)`

That css looks like this.

```
.team-card:nth-child(5):hover ~ .team-card:nth-child(n+4){
  transform: translateX(30px);
}
```

Per this article on css tricks, https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/, doing the first 4 should also be easy.

```
.team-card:nth-child(5):hover ~ .team-card:nth-child(-n+4){
  transform: translateX(-30px);
}
```

But this doesn't work. I've tried removing the first css selector, thinking that maybe you couldn't have more than a single hover psuedo-state on a class. But that didn't do anything.

Then I removed the hover state so I just had this.

```
.team-card:nth-child(-n+4){
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

And that worked. So does `nth-child` using `-n` not work when it has a psuedo-state?

[image: yellow]

Is there a pure css solution to achieve this effect when hovering? Or will I have to resort to javascript?

[image]

EDIT:

Here is the fiddle that I forgot to link to.

https://jsfiddle.net/q0x51kmw/1/

Comment: you cannot target previous element by hover on an element

Comment: Gotcha. So I'll have to resort to a javascript solution then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this very simply, without the transform property:

```css
.team-cards-container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 55px 2.5%;
  height: 300px;
}

.team-card {
  flex: 1;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.team-card:hover {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

/*Colors*/
.team-card:nth-child(3n+1) {background-color: #949300}
.team-card:nth-child(3n+2) {background-color: #8A1B61}
.team-card:nth-child(3n+3) {background-color: #236192}
.team-card:nth-child(5) {background: #ff0000}
```

```html
<div class="team-cards-container">
  <div class="team-card"></div>
  <div class="team-card"></div>
  <div class="team-card"></div>
  <div class="team-card"></div>
  <div class="team-card"></div>
  <div class="team-card"></div>
  <div class="team-card"></div>
  <div class="team-card"></div>
  <div class="team-card"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you mean?

- `.team-cards-container` hover moves all children -30px
- current (child) `.team-card` hover overwrites to 0px
- all next siblings to current `.team-card` hover are overwritten +30px

```css
.team-cards-container{
  display:flex;
  width:95%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  padding-top:55px;
}

/*Colors*/
.team-card:nth-child(3n+1){
  height:300px; 
  width:230px;
  background-color:#949300;
}
.team-card:nth-child(3n+2){
  height:300px; 
  width:230px;
  background-color:#8A1B61;
}
.team-card:nth-child(3n+3){
  height:300px; 
  width:230px;
  background-color:#236192;
}

/*Middle*/
.team-card:nth-child(5){
  background:red;
}

/*Universals*/
.team-card{
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.team-cards-container:hover .team-card {
  transform: translateX(-30px);
}
.team-cards-container .team-card:hover {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.team-card:hover ~ .team-card {
  transform: translateX(30px);
}
```

```html
<div class="team-cards-container">
  <div class="team-card"></div>
  <div class="team-card"></div>
  <div class="team-card"></div>
  <div class="team-card"></div>
  <div class="team-card"></div>
  <div class="team-card"></div>
  <div class="team-card"></div>
  <div class="team-card"></div>
  <div class="team-card"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm after. Very clever. And thank you for adding the explanation. I'll be accepting this answer when the timer allows.

Comment: @onTheInternet see my answer, you can do this in a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

css do not allow you to style previous sibling element. You are using '~' but '~' can only be used to style next sibling elements

you are doing it the wrong way

replace your css with this

```
.team-cards-container{
  display:flex;
  width:95%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  padding-top:55px;
}

/*Colors*/
.team-card:nth-child(3n+1){
  height:300px; 
  width:230px;
  background-color:#949300;
}
.team-card:nth-child(3n+2){
  height:300px; 
  width:230px;
  background-color:#8A1B61;
}
.team-card:nth-child(3n+3){
  height:300px; 
  width:230px;
  background-color:#236192;
}

/*Middle*/
.team-card:nth-child(5){
  background:red;
}

/*Universals*/
.team-card{
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}


.team-cards-container:hover > .team-card{
  transform:translateX(-20px);
}

.team-card:hover{
  transform:translateX(0px)!important;
}


.team-card:hover~.team-card{
  transform:translateX(20px)!important;
}
```